# Updating a config file in c#

Tags: c#, file, config, updates, difference

I am creating an update to my companies system that will be running on several clients and I have two config files, the old config file and the newer version.
Is there any way that I can compare the both files and check the differences to add to the older file what I have new in the first one?
Keep in mind that the files may have different info and the only thing that I need to add/change is the keys. For example, if a key is different change the older to that new "version", if a key doesn’t exist in the older files add it.

they keys will have the exact same name but may have different values. Plus there could be a new key that doesnt exist in the older file and I need to add it

I will leave an example of the files for you to see,

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ORCASRV1"            value="ORCA30|tcp://127.0.0.1:9001" />
    <add key="ORCASRV2"            value="REORCA30|tcp://127.0.0.1:9001" />
    <add key="ServidorEmail"       value="xxx" />
    <add key="SqlTrans"            value="1" />
    <add key="RemoteType"          value="0" />
    <add key="LocalPort"           value="9002" />
    <add key="LocalMsgStore"       value="1" />
    <add key="sqlCHAR_TO_DATA"     value="CONVERT(datetime, '#MM#/#DD#/#YYYY#')" />
    <add key="sqlDATA_TO_CHAR"     value="CONVERT(char(30), #CAMPO#)" />
    <add key="sqlDATAPARTE"        value="LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(#PARTE, #CAMPO#)))" />
    <add key="sqlNUM_TO_CHAR"      value="LTRIM(STR(#VALOR#))" />
    <add key="sqlSYSDATE"          value=" GetDate() " />
    <add key="sqlALIAS"            value=" As " />
    <add key="sqlCONCATENAR"       value="+" />    <add key="sqlNULL"             value="IsNull(#CAMPO#,#VALOR#)" />
    <add key="sqlROUND"            value="ROUND(#CAMPO#,#PARTE#)" />
    <add key="sqlLPAD"             value="RIGTH(REPLICATE('#CHAR#',#VEZES#)+#CAMPO#,#VEZES#)" />
    <add key="oraCHAR_TO_DATA"     value="TO_DATE('#MM#/#DD#/#YYYY#','MM/DD/YYYY')" />
    <add key="oraDATA_TO_CHAR"     value="TO_CHAR(#CAMPO#, 'DD/MM/YYYY')" />
    <add key="oraDATAPARTE"        value="TO_CHAR(#PARTE#, #CAMPO#)" />
    <add key="oraNUM_TO_CHAR"      value="TO_CHAR(#VALOR#)" />
    <add key="oraSYSDATE"          value=" SYSDATE " />
    <add key="oraALIAS"            value=" " />
    <add key="oraCONCATENAR"       value="||" />
    <add key="oraNULL"             value="NVL(#CAMPO#,#VALOR#)" />
    <add key="oraROUND"            value="ROUND(#CAMPO#,#PARTE#)" />
    <add key="oraLPAD"             value="LPAD(#CAMPO#,#VEZES#,#CHAR#)" />
    <add key="EmailCDP"            value="antonio.santos@cdp-si.pt" />
    <add key="EmailCliente"        value="xxx" />
    <add key="RPT_PATH1"           value="C:\PROD\ORCAREPORT\" />
    <add key="StartPage_Height"    value="90" />
    <add key="StartPage_Margem"    value="220" />
    <add key="StartPage_Espaco"    value="5" />
    <add key="StartPage_Intervalo" value="2" />
    <add key="StartPage_Mais"      value="35" />
    <add key="HelpExec"            value="WINHLP32.EXE" />
    <add key="HelpFile"            value="ORCA.HLP" />
    <add key="LogLevel"            value="0" />
    <add key="LogSqlClient"        value="0" />
    <add key="LogFile"             value="C:\cdpsi\logs" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="9002">
          <clientProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" />            <provider type="CdpCompress.CompressionClientSinkProvider, CdpCompress" />
          </clientProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How would you know if two different keys are related?  Are they in the same position in the file, are the values the same?  How do you disambiguate between what could possibly be a new key or a key where the name has been changed?

Comment: they keys will have the exact same name but may have different values.
Plus there could be a new key that doesnt exist in the older file and I need to add it

Comment: Why do you want to do this programmatically? Unless the config file changes everyday, it is a total pointless script to write. For just one time thing, why not compare the file using windiff and add/update keys manually?

Comment: I can't do it manually cause there will me many clients that need to update their system when new packages come out and I cant be doing that on 50 machines manually hence the programm

Comment: So parse xml to Dictionary<string,string> and compare new dictionary with old. How do You keep operational configuration, how is "internally" implemented?

Comment: Im in an intership so I dont have that "Knowledge" I just know that they lost their installer and now they do all the updates via packages.
if it's not that what ur asking sorry for not understanding :\
Can you give an example of that dictionary method pls?

Comment: @JacekCz that was what I eventually did and works perfectly. If you want post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code went like this and it works like a charm:

```
public void UpdateService(string FilePathOld, string FilePathNew, string LatestVersion)
{
        Dictionary<string, string> Old = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> New = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (ExisteFicheiro(FilePathNew) == true && ExisteFicheiro(FilePathOld) == true)
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configOld.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathOld;
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            ExeConfigurationFileMap configNew = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configNew.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathNew;
            Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configNew, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
            Old = settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings2 = config2.AppSettings.Settings;
            New = settings2.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings2[key].Value);

            foreach (var NewKey in New)
            {
                string value;
                if (Old.TryGetValue(NewKey.Key, out value))
                {
                    if (value != NewKey.Value)
                    {
                        //if (ExistsKey(NewKey.Key, false) == true)
                        Old[NewKey.Key] = NewKey.Value;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Old.Add(NewKey.Key, NewKey.Value);
                }
            }

            foreach (var NewKey in Old)
            {
                string key = NewKey.Key;
                string value = NewKey.Value;
                if (config.AppSettings.Settings[key] != null)
                {
                    config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
                    if (key == "Version")
                        config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = LatestVersion;
                }
                else
                {
                    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);

                }
                if (config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"] == null)
                {
                    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Version", LatestVersion);
                }

            }
            config.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            Erro NovoErro = new Erro();
            Global.Erro = "O ficheiro \"OrcaService.exe.config\" ou o ficheiro \"Orca.exe.config\" não existem nos caminhos especificados!";
        }

}
```