# Ordering a List by string to find the newer version C#

Tags: c#, sorting, directory, version

I have a folder with several Directories that are named after a version of an update such as UPDATE_20080311_3.5.9.
I need to find the latest update on that list by veryfing the "3.5.9", I made a code to parse the name and add just the version to a list.
Is there anyway to Sort tha list by using List.Sort in order to get the latest version "number"?
This is the code I made so far, I don't know how to properly use the .Sort() method and if this can be done.
I appreciate any help given

```
public string NewerVersion(string Directoria)
    {
        List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo Info in dirs)
        {
            string Dir = Info.Name.ToString();
            Lista.Add(Dir.Substring(Dir.LastIndexOf('_'), Dir.Length));

        }
        Lista.Sort()
        //Lista.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a true numeric sort, e.g. is `3.5.11` greater than `3.5.9`?

Comment: Yes exactly like that. Because from that list I need to find the newest version

Comment: for example this list:
2.5.1,
3.5.9,
3.5.10,
4.5.6,

I need to be able to get the "4.5.6" since it's the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Continuing from your solution, there is a problem which the way you add your item:

```
string Dir = Info.Name.ToString();
Lista.Add(Dir.Substring(Dir.LastIndexOf('_'), Dir.Length));
```

Notice two mistakes here:

1. You get the `Substring` from `LastIndexOf('_')` instead of from `LastIndexOf('_') + 1`, which is what you really want
2. You use `Dir.Length` while you should use `Dir.Length - LastIndexOf('_') + 1` instead

Change that into:

```
string Dir = Info.Name.ToString();
int indexStart = Dir.LastIndexOf('_') + 1;
Lista.Add(Dir.Substring(indexStart, Dir.Length - indexStart));
```

Then you could further process the `Lista` that you have populated to have the version number alone by `LINQ` `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` as well as `string.Split('.')`

```
var result = Lista.Select(x => x.Split('.'))
    .OrderBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a[0]))
    .ThenBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a[1]))
    .ThenBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a[2]))
    .Last();
string finalVersion = string.Join(".", result);
```

To get the final version among the listed items.

To get your directory path back based on your `finalVersion`, simply do:

```
string myDirPath = dirs.Select(x => x.FullName).SingleOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(finalVersion));
```

Comment: In the end I need to get the full name of that directory.

Comment: @Mr.Toxy which you do have, in your `dirs` ;) you could get it back by: `dirs.Select(x => x.FullName).SingleOrDefault(a => a.EndsWith(finalVersion));`

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help.
I will test your method

Comment: Now the only problem is my susbtring wich wont work despite everything I change to make it work correctly

Comment: @Mr.Toxy "my substring won't work" ... won't work as in...?

Comment: @Mr.Toxy ah, I can see where you got it wrong, you use `Dir.Length`

Comment: oh yeah ahahahaha it will give an error :p it is working xD but it aint properly done

Comment: Damn it works like a charm. Thank you so so much, you've spare me some more headicks thx so much :D

Comment: @Mr.Toxy no problem. ;) be careful of the string position when you use `Substring`. It often confusing. :)

Comment: can you shed some light on this pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570501/updating-a-config-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Mr.Toxy ugh... it seems like it is problem of XML... I know the tool, by I myself seldom use it. read your XML using `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();` then use some items in the XML parser to handle the files further...

Comment: sorry to bother  you so damn much but I never used Linq before and it's hard to understand at first for me, I've analyzed the code but can't fully understand. Some of the changes that they asked me to do is to find the newest setup out of a list with folders named like this: Setup15, Setup14, Setup16... Hoe can I adapt your code in order to find the newest as we did above?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `IComparable`, so it supports sorting.

For example with this LINQ query:

```
Version version = null;
Version lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria).EnumerateDirectories()
    .Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("UPDATE_"))
    .Select(d => new {Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_')})
    .Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version))
    .Select(x => new {x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
    .Select(x => x.Version)
    .FirstOrDefault();
string latestVersion = lastVersion.ToString(); // if you want it as string
```

> After I find the newer version I need to be able to return the name
>   of the directory

Then use this query:

```
var lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria).EnumerateDirectories()
    .Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("UPDATE_"))
    .Select(d => new {Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_')})
    .Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version))
    .Select(x => new {x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (lastVersion != null)
    Console.WriteLine(lastVersion.Directory.FullName);
```

Comment: Was just about writing an answer with shitty splits and text sortings. Holy shit havnt known there is a `Version` class. Thanks!

Comment: After I find the newer version I need to be able to return the name of the directory

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: Done. Note that you also could check if there's a version that is greater than(or equal to) `3.5.9`. You just need to modify the `Where` in this way: `.Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version) && version >= new Version("3.5.9"))` (initialize it once in a variable before the query).

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry for the ignorance but Im a little lost.
The only difference between the two queries that you mentioned are what they return right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter will this method also work for newer versions like 4.1.1 or any other.?
Let's assum that this will have to work for any version

Comment: Of course it will work, and yes, the second query is just a little modification. You already have all you need in the anonymous type

Comment: @TimSchmelter on this line .Select(x => new {x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version}) where the Version = version is, the "version" variable appears as not initialized

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: you mean you get a compiler error? Then you haven't used my current code where i initialize it with null: `Version version = null;`. That it gets a valid version is ensured with the second condition in the `Where`: `Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter oups, ur right. I totally missed that reference. Thank you :D

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry to bother so mucch but I never used Linq before and its kind of confusing to me.
Some of the changes that they asked me to do is to find the newest setup out of a list with folders named like this:
Setup15, Setup14, Setup16...
Hoe can I adapt your code in order to find the newest as we did above?

Comment: Replace `UPDATE_` with `Setup` and use `int.Parse` to convert the substring to an `int` which you can use for the order. If you don't know what to do create another question and explain it well. If you post a comment with the link to that question here i can try to answer it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597030/searching-for-the-newest-update-in-a-directory-c-sharp
Done ;)

Answer (score 2):

When sorting by *version*, try using `Version` which is specially designed for that:

```
 List<String> Lista = new List<string>() {
    "UPDATE_20080311_3.5.9",
    "UPDATE_20080311_3.5.10",
    "UPDATE_20080311_3.4.11",
  };

  Lista.Sort((left, right) => {
    Version x = new Version(left.Substring(left.LastIndexOf('_') + 1));
    Version y = new Version(right.Substring(right.LastIndexOf('_') + 1));

    // or "return -x.CompareTo(y);" if you want to sort in descending order
    return x.CompareTo(y);
  });

  ...

  // UPDATE_20080311_3.4.11
  // UPDATE_20080311_3.5.9
  // UPDATE_20080311_3.5.10
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lista);
```

Comment: this method will put the newer version in the first "index" of the list?
Sorry for the weird question but how can I return it if its not guaranteed that a list is orderly searched?

Comment: @Mr.Toxy, no the *older* one will be on the *top*, to reverse (sort in *descending order*) put `-` before  `x.CompareTo(y);`: `return -x.CompareTo(y);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq` and [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx)

```
public string NewerVersion(string Directoria)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(Directoria)
        .GetDirectories()
        .OrderByDescending(x => new Version(x.Name.Substring(x.Name.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)))
        .First()
        .Name;
}
```

If Directoria contains `"UPDATE_20080311_3.5.9", "UPDATE_20090311_5.6.11", "UPDATE_20070311_1.5.9"`, will return `"UPDATE_20090311_5.6.11"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about, whether this satisfies the requirement or not;if not please forgive me;

You are creating folders for each version release; so a version 3.5.7 will be created after `3.5.6` which is followed by `3.55` and the next version could be `3.58`, So what i'am trying to say is that, they can be sorted on the basics of creation time. if so the following code will help you:

```
public static string NewerVersion(string Directoria)
{
    List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
    Lista = dirs.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).Select(y => y.Name.ToString()).ToList();
    //Lista will contains the required names
    //rest of code here
    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lista);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I dont think this method will work because I dont know how they deploy the versions. They just told me to search the newest by the version "number".