# Searching for the newest update in a directory c#

Tags: c#, linq, updates

I have directory named Updates that inside has many folders named Update10, Update15,Update13 and so on.
I need to be able to get the most recent update by comparing the numbers on the folder name and return the path to that folder.
Any help would be aprecciated

Comment: Every folder starts with the word "Update" followed by one or more digits? And the higher number is the latest one?

Comment: Shouldn't the date created / modified be much more accurate ?

Comment: I'm sure you could give this a go.  Post something you've tried

Comment: What's the betting that the numbering goes `Update1`, `Update2`, ..., `Update9`, `Update10`, thus stymying any straightforward attempt to sort by name. ;)

Comment: 1. Every folder will start with "Update", 
2. I can't rely on the date, 
3. I have tried using linq but can't figure out the syntax, 
4. The highest number is indeed the most recent update yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
int updateInt = 0;

var mostRecendUpdate = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(updateDir)
    .Select(path => new
    {
        fullPath = path,
        directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path) // returns f.e. Update15
    })
    .Where(x => x.directoryName.StartsWith("Update"))    // precheck
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.fullPath, x.directoryName,
        updStr = x.directoryName.Substring("Update".Length) // returns f.e. "15"
    })
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x.updStr, out updateInt))      // int-check and initialization of updateInt
    .Select(x => new { x.fullPath, x.directoryName, update = updateInt })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.update)                       // main task: sorting
    .FirstOrDefault();                                      // return newest update-infos

if(mostRecendUpdate != null)
{
    string fullPath = mostRecendUpdate.fullPath;
    int update = mostRecendUpdate.update;
}
```

A [cleaner version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16613455/284240) uses a method that returns an `int?` instead of using the local variable as out-parameter because LINQ should not cause such side-effects. They could be harmful.

One note:  currently the query is case sensitive,  it won't recognize `UPDATE11` as valid directory. If you want to compare case-insensitive you have to use the appropriate `StartsWith` overload:

```
.....
.Where(x => x.directoryName.StartsWith("Update", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))    // precheck
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

This function uses LINQ to get the last update directory path.

```
public string GetLatestUpdate(string path)
{
    if (!path.EndsWith("\\")) path += "\\";
    return System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                    .Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, long>(f, long.Parse(f.Remove(0, (path + "Update").Length))))
                    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value)
                    .First().Key;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use modified date as comments in question suggests. 
however to sort strings as numbers you can go for making use of IComparer. 
This has already been done and can be found in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C)

*edit with sample*

after you get the directories:

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories();
var numComp = new NumericComparer();
Array.Sort(dirs, numComp);
```

the last item in **dirs** is your last "modified" directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the creation date of the folders, you can simplify this by making use of [MoreLinq's `MaxBy()`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/2.0.0-beta03):

```
string updatesFolder = "D:\\TEST\\Updates"; // Your path goes here.
var newest = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(updatesFolder, "Update*")
                      .MaxBy(folder => new DirectoryInfo(folder).CreationTime);
```

For reference, an implementation of `MaxBy()` is:

```
public static class EnumerableMaxMinExt
{
    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
            }

            TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey maxKey = selector(max);

            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);

                if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
                {
                    max = candidate;
                    maxKey = candidateProjected;
                }
            }

            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the dates :\